# Progress var using canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a circle progress bar circle to show my skills but since I put a setInterval function, It doesn't work. I think the ligne context.arc() doesn't take the values and so it shows nothing, but I can't get throught this problem, how can i do ? Thank you in advance

HTML :

```
  <section id="skills">
        <div class="load-container">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
            <span id="percent"></span>
        </div>
       
    </section>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script>
class Circle
        {
            constructor(x, y, percent)
            {
                this.posX = x;
                this.posY = y;
                this.percent = percent;
                this.radius = 100;
            }

            drawing(context)
            {
                let unitValue = (Math.PI - 0.5 * Math.PI) / 25;
                let startAngle = 0;
                let endAngle = startAngle + (this.percent * unitValue);
                let arcInterval = setInterval (function() 
                {
                    startAngle += 1;

                     /*grey circle*/
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, startAngle, (2 * Math.PI), false);
                    context.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
                    context.lineWidth = '10';
                    context.stroke();

                    /*blue circle*/
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
                    context.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
                    context.lineWidth = '10';
                    context.stroke();

                    if (startAngle >= endAngle)
                        {
                            clearInterval(arcInterval);
                        }
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        function setup()
        {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
       
            /*draw the circles*/
            let circle = new Circle(150, 200, 86);
            circle.drawing(context);
            let circle2 = new Circle(400, 200, 76);
            circle2.drawing(context);
            let circle3 = new Circle(650, 200, 44);
            circle3.drawing(context);
            let circle4 = new Circle(150, 450, 35);
            circle4.drawing(context);

        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
           setup();
        }
       
        
</script>
```

Comment: You need to pass `this` reference into the anonymous `callback` function that you call inside setInterval. You may try `let arcInterval = setInterval(function(){//yourcode}.bind(this), 500)`

Comment: (Math.PI - 0.5 * Math.PI)    ~~   (0.5 * Math.PI) ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work but not yet for the transition... I changed startAngle++ with unitValue++ but no result, if you have an idea again ^^ ?

Comment: @Florent I have seen this page : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it...

Keep your class Circle code as small as possible, and do the loop (setInterval) in the setup, that way you can clear the entire canvas there, I think that is a better way.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
  }

  drawing(context, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.posX, this.posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

function setup() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let startAngle = 0;
  let endAngle = 2 * Math.PI

  /*draw the circles*/
  let circle = new Circle(30, 30);
  let circ2 = new Circle(60, 80);
  let circ3 = new Circle(80, 40);

  let arcInterval = setInterval(function() {
    startAngle += 0.1;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 180, 180);
    circle.drawing(context, 20, startAngle, endAngle - 1);
    circ2.drawing(context, 20, startAngle - 1, endAngle);
    circ3.drawing(context, 15 - startAngle * 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    if (startAngle > endAngle) {
      clearInterval(arcInterval);
    }
  }, 100);
}

window.onload = function() {
  setup();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

As you can see I'm passing multiple parameters to the drawing function:
`drawing(context, radius, startAngle, endAngle)`
that way we can control those parameters from the loop, and with a bit of math you can make the progress animation more fun, but I let you to fine-tune that.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I'm still stuck but thank you for your advise

Comment: If the answer was useful please up-vote it ... and if you are stuck just ask another question and it looks like you did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449396/multiple-progress-bars-using-canvas-and-javascript-objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've just changed the step count. You may change it from 5 to what ever you want.

```
<script>
    class Circle {
      constructor(x, y, percent) {
        this.posX = x;
        this.posY = y;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.radius = 100;
        this.arcInterval = null; // Changed
      }

      drawCallback(ctx, start, end) { // Added
        let inc = 1;
        return () => {
          inc += 1;
          console.log(inc);

          drawArc(ctx, this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, '#3949AB', start, end * inc / 5);

          if (inc > 5) {
            clearInterval(this.arcInterval);
          }
        }
      }

      drawing(context) { // Added
        let unitValue = 0.5 * Math.PI / 25; // Changed
        const startAngle = 0; // Changed
        const endAngle = startAngle + (this.percent * unitValue); // Changed

        /* grey circle */
        drawArc(context, this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, '#b1b1b1', startAngle, 2 * Math.PI); // Changed
        
        /* blue circle */
        this.arcInterval = setInterval(this.drawCallback(context, startAngle, endAngle), 500); // Changed
      }
    }

    function drawArc(ctx, posX, posY, radius, color, startAngle, endAngle) { // Added
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.lineWidth = '10';
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    function setup() {
      let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      /*draw the circles*/
      let circle = new Circle(150, 200, 86);
      circle.drawing(context);
      let circle2 = new Circle(400, 200, 76);
      circle2.drawing(context);
      let circle3 = new Circle(650, 200, 44);
      circle3.drawing(context);
      let circle4 = new Circle(150, 450, 35);
      circle4.drawing(context);

    }

    window.onload = function () {
      setup();
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it still doesn't work with your code

Comment: Take it and past in the new html. It should work. I checked. Do you have a special setup for your workspace?

Comment: It works but not for the first circle, 86% should not give a full circle

Comment: No i use visual studio code and nothing else of special

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
 <section id="skills">
        <div class="load-container">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
            <span id="percent"></span>
        </div>
       
 </section>


<script>
class Circle
        {
            constructor(x, y, percent)  {
                this.posX = x;
                this.posY = y;
                this.percent = percent;
                this.radius = 100;
                this.startAngle = 0; // <---
                this.unitValue = (Math.PI - 0.5 * Math.PI) / 25; // 
                this.endAngle = this.startAngle + (this.percent * this.unitValue);              
            }

            drawing(context) {
                this.arcInterval = setInterval (function(ctx,that)  {
                    that.startAngle += 1;

                     /*grey circle*/
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(that.posX, that.posY, that.radius, that.startAngle, (2 * Math.PI), false);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
                    ctx.lineWidth = '10';
                    ctx.stroke();

                    /*blue circle*/
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(that.posX, that.posY, that.radius, that.startAngle, that.endAngle, false);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
                    ctx.lineWidth = '10';
                    ctx.stroke();

                    // Why stop ? 
                    // if (that.startAngle >= that.endAngle) {  clearInterval(that.arcInterval);  }
                }, 500,context, this); // <------ this -> that and context -> ctx
            }
        }

        function setup() {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            /*create circles*/
            window.myCircles = [new Circle(150, 200, 86), 
                                 new Circle(400, 200, 76),
                                 new Circle(650, 200, 44), 
                                 new Circle(150, 450, 35)];
        
            for (let o of window.myCircles) { o.drawing(context); }
        }
        window.onload = function()  {  setup(); }
          
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

You can try the funny way ->

```
class Circle
        {
            constructor(x, y, percent)  {
                this.posX = x;
                this.posY = y;
                this.percent = percent;
                this.radius = 100;
                this.startAngle = 0; // <---
                this.unitValue = (Math.PI - 0.5 * Math.PI) / 25; // 
                this.endAngle = this.startAngle + (this.percent * this.unitValue);              
            }

            drawing(context) {
                this.arcInterval = setInterval (function(ctx,that)  {
                    that.startAngle += 1;

                     /*grey circle*/
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(that.posX, that.posY, that.radius, that.startAngle, (2 * Math.PI), false);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
                    ctx.lineWidth = '10';
                    ctx.stroke();

                    /*blue circle*/
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(that.posX, that.posY, that.radius, that.startAngle, that.endAngle, false);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
                    ctx.lineWidth = '10';
                    ctx.stroke();

                    // Why stop ? 
                    // if (that.startAngle >= that.endAngle) {  clearInterval(that.arcInterval);  }
                }, 500,context, this); // <------ this -> that and context -> ctx
            }
        }

        function setup() {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            /*create circles*/
            window.myCircles = [new Circle(150, 200, 86), 
                                 new Circle(400, 200, 76),
                                 new Circle(650, 200, 44), 
                                 new Circle(150, 450, 35)];
        
            for (let o of window.myCircles) { o.drawing(context); }
        }
        window.onload = function()  {  setup(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I've put your code and it doesn't work

Comment: I had the snippet